# Find all regular files that were modified less recently than another file

Tags: find

Find all regular files that were modified less recently than the *** file (which can be found in @@@/###/&&&).

How can I solve this problem? Please tell me various methods.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? have you read the manual page for the `find` command - in particular the `-newer file` test?

Answer (score 2):

Read `man find`

```
find /pathwheretosearch -newer /pathtofile/filename -type f
```